# Python: Even if the the if statement equals false it still executes the code inside the if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Even if the the if statement equals false it still executes the code inside the if statement.
Here is the code:

```
# Imports:
import time

# Code Starts Here:
print("Welcome to a test application By: David(Toxicminibro)")
time.sleep(1.25)

Donald = "Donald Trump"
donald = "donald trump"
Hillary = "Hillary Clinton"
hillary = "hillary clinton"

name = input("What is your name?: ")

if name == Donald or donald or Hillary or hillary:
    print("No. Stop it.")
else:
    print("Hello " + name + " !")
```

Comment: `if (name == Donald) or (donald) or (Hillary) or (hillary):` Since `donald` evaluates to `True`, it will run `print("No. Stop it.")`.

Comment: Maybe you see the problem if I add some perapherances: `if (name == Donald) or (donald) or (Hillary) or (hillary):` BTW non-empty strings are considered `True` in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if name in (Donald, donald, Hillary, hillary):
    print("No. Stop it.")
else:
    print("Hello " + name + " !")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to do :

```
if name == Donald or name == donald or name == Hillary or name == hillary:
```

Have a [look at this link](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html); it explains how various values are considered to be "true" or "false"

Answer (score 1):

A more Pythonic way of doing this is: `if name.lower() in [donald, hillary]:`